# Cauchy's problem $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$, $y$ globally Lipschitz $\rightarrow$ $y$ is a global solution?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We have a Cauchy's problem like it :

$$\begin{cases}
y'(t) = f(t,y(t))\\
y(t_0) = y_0 
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous and $C^1$ and the maximal solution $y(t)$ is defined on a maximal interval. I read that if $y'$ is bounded, $y$ is globally Lipschitz and the maximal solution of the problem is global.

Someone has a demonstration to prove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the maximal interval is $(a,b)$ where, w.l.og., $b<\infty$. Because of Lipschitz continuity $y_b=\lim_{x\to b}y(x)$ exists and the IVP with $y(b)=y_b$ has a local solution.

Now that solution can be used to continue the given solution outside $(a,b)$, thus contradicting the maximality.